# php - Retrieve value from $_SESSION and output using another variable

Tags: php, session, variables, global-variables

I know `$_SESSION` is a global variable but I don't know how to retrieve the value it stores.

For example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]))
{
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        //set variables to use in content below
        $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        
        echo '<p>'.$product_name.'</p>';
        echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></p>';
    }
}

echo $_SESSION["cart_products"];
?>
```

Here you can see, the `$_SESSION["cart_products"]` holds some value (information like product name, product code etc). Now, the problem is that I just want to echo out all the product names that are stored in `$_SESSION["cart_products"]`.

Since it's a *cart list*, it contains more than *one* product details. But, when I echo out `$product_name`, it only shows the name of the *last product* in the list. And echoing out `$_SESSION["cart_products"]` gives `array to string` error.

How can I list out all the product names separating by a `,`?

I have already tried using the `implode()` function.

Comment: you can't echo an array. outputting an array in string context, e.g. `$foo = array(); echo $foo` will simply produce the literal text `Array`. And exactly how/where are you outputting `$product_name`? Once your loop exits, `$product_name` will contain the LAST item you looped on, and then won't change again.

Comment: use print_r($_SESSION["cart_products"]) function for display all the data...not echo because $_SESSION["cart_products"] is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer to my query with the help of @Christophe Ferreboeuf. However, some modification was still needed.

Here's the corrected code:

```
$allProductName = '';
 $prefix = '';
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    $allProductName .= $prefix . '"' . $cart_itm["product_name"]. '"';
    $prefix = ', ';
}
echo $allProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

for displaying all the product name separated by , use this code.

```
$allProductName = '';
 $prefix = '';
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    $allProductName .= $prefix . '"' . $product_name. '"';
    $prefix = ', ';
}
echo $allProductName;
```

Comment: You solution only prints the **last product** name. If I have 3 different items in my list, then it is printing the last product name 3 times.

Comment: @Adictonator If you find that you need to modify this answer's code in order to get it working, you should post that as your own answer rather than editing this one.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks you. I didn't know that. Will do that now.

Comment: @shut The output was an array string.
`Array ( [PD1002] => Array ( [product_code] => PD1002 [product_name] => Television DXT ) [PD1003] => Array ( [product_code] => PD1003 [product_name] => External Hard Disk ) [PD1001] => Array ( [product_code] => PD1001 [product_name] => Android Phone FX1 ) ) "Television DXT", "External Hard Disk", "Android Phone FX1"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a edited version of your code

```
<?php
    //you need to start session first
    session_start();
    $item = ["product_name" => "BMW", "product_code" => "540M"];
    $list = array( $item, $item );

    // Assuming you session list 
    $_SESSION[ "cart_products" ] = $list;

    if(isset( $_SESSION["cart_products"])) {
        foreach ( $_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm ) {
            //set variables to use in content below
            $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
            $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];

            echo '<p>'.$product_name.'</p>';
            echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></p>';
        }

        // to print names seperated by ','
        $temp = "";
        foreach ( $_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm ) {
            $temp .= $cart_itm["product_name"] . ", ";
        }

        echo $temp;
    }

    // you cant print array using echo directly
    print_r( $_SESSION["cart_products"] );

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Priyesh for your help but I got it sorted out by the other's solution. I appreciate your help, though.